# create a complex query?

Tags: python, django

create a complex query?

please help to solve the problem.

I wrote a filter to search for people. Filter contains 2 fields: "name", "birth_date"

friends_search.html:

```
<form class="left filter" action="{% url 'friends_search' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label lbl_name" for="fld_name">Имя</label>

        <input class="fld_name" type="text" name="fld_name" id="fld_name" value="{% if post.fld_name %}{{ post.fld_name }}{% endif %}" />
    </div>          

    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label lbl_birth_date" for="fld_birth_date">Дата рождения</label>

        <input class="fld_birth_date datepicker" type="text" name="fld_birth_date" id="fld_birth_date" value="{% if post.fld_birth_date %}{{ post.fld_birth_date }}{% endif %}" />
    </div>                  

    <div class="cell">
        <input class="submit btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="fld_submit" id="fld_submit" value="Найти" />
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
@login_required 
def friends_search(request):
    search_result = None
    post = None

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        post = request.POST

        if request.POST.get('fld_name'):
            try:
                fld_name = request.POST.get('fld_name')
                fld_birth_date = request.POST.get('fld_birth_date')

                if q_name:
                    q_name = Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name.strip()))               

                if q_birth_date:
                    q_birth_date = Q(birth_date__icontains=fld_birth_date.strip())

                search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter(q_name).filter(q_birth_date)     #???????????????????????????    
                if not search_result:
                    search_result = 'null'
            except Exception as exc:
                search_result = 'error' 

    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'city_list': UserProfile.get_city_list(),
        'post': post,
    }]) 
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(User):    
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Отображаемое имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=False,
    )
    birth_date = models.DateField(
        'Дата рождения',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

the problem is that I can not look from two fields:

```
search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter (q_name). filter (q_birth_date)
```

but I can search for specific fields:

```
search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter (q_name)
```

&

```
search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter (q_birth_date)
```

I need you to search using two fields simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, ever catch the base class `Exception` unless you handle it properly (i.e. log the error message etc.). Why? Because that `except` clause hides the real problems in your code and makes debugging a huge pain in the ass.

The `request.POST` object only contains plain strings. While `fld_birth_date` may be a date-formatted string, you can't filter a `DateField` with a string object. You need an actual `date` object to filter.

What you need to do is convert the string to a date object. E.g. if your date always follows the format `dd-mm-YYYY`, you can do:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strftime(request.POST.get('fld_birth_date'), '%d-%m-%Y').date()
```

On top of that, you use `if q_name` and `if q_birth_date` while neither are defined at all, both raising another exception.

The `if request.method == 'POST'` part of your code should probably look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('fld_name', None)
    birth_date_string = request.POST.get('fld_birth_date', '')
    try:
        birth_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(birth_date_string, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
    except ValueError:
        birth_date = None

    search_results = UserProfile.objects.all()
    if name:
        search_results = search_results.filter(name__icontains=name.strip())
    if birth_date:
        search_results = search_results.filter(birth_date=birth_date)
```

Or if you want a result if either name or birth_date matches:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q()
if name:
    q |= Q(name__icontains=name.strip())
if birth_date:
    q |= Q(birth_date=birth_date)
search_results = UserProfile.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: thanks. but this string search_results = UserProfile.objects.all() generate: Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Wait, what? Can you post your `UserProfile` class?

Answer (score 2):

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(q_name).filter(q_birth_date)
```

Will search for both ie. nickname is something *AND* birth_date is something.

If you want to search on either one of them or both fields you can update your view as

```
            fld_name = request.POST.get('fld_name')
            fld_birth_date = request.POST.get('fld_birth_date')

            qs = UserProfile.objects.filter() #get all

            if fld_name:
                qs = qs.filter(nickname__icontains=fld_name.strip()))               

            if fld_birth_date:
                qs = qs.filter(birth_date__icontains=fld_birth_date.strip())

            search_result = qs     
            if not search_result:
                search_result = 'null'
```

You can do away with `search_result` variable as `qs` is same as that.

Comment: the fact is that I do not know what kind of data will come to the controller: 
q_name 

or 

q_birth_date 

or 

q_birth_date, q_name